# Detect end of Touch Drag Outside

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, touch

I have a Touch Drag Outside event on a button, and I would like to detect and run a method when the user stops dragging and lifts the finger of the screen again. I could not find an event to match that in the button, and touchesEnded did not work either. 
How can that be done?

Comment: This `[button addTarget:self action:@selector(go) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];`?

Answer (score 0):

You should go with `touchesCancelled:withEvent:`

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use "PangestureRecognizer" in this case and can determine the states of gestures

if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
{

//do something

}

else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) 
{

//do something

}
else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{

//do something

}
```